# Extjs 5 to 6 migration, TreeView layout looks different

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, layout

I have migrate from extjs 5 to 6. On my application I have used `Ext.tree.Panel` simple tree view:

[image: how tree looks on extjs 5]

and after changing extjs libraries to version 6:

[image: how tree looks on extjs 6]

As you can see, layout on extjs 6 is not working correctly.

```
Ext.define('SupComWebApp.view.TestTree', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.testtree',
renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    root: {
        text: 'Root Node',
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            {
                text: 'Child 1',
                leaf: true
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2',
                leaf: true
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 3',
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        text: 'Grandchild',
                        leaf: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
 });
```

Comment: Looks fine: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/140u

Comment: Check the Upgrade Guide : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/upgrades_migrations/extjs_upgrade_guide.html

Comment: Yes even with the classic framework it looks fine. You should check if your theming is the original from the ZIP file without any tuning.